# Combine results from multiple models

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, machine-learning-model

I am using chunks of 100000 rows at a time from the CSV file to train the a simple LASSO model.

How do I combine all of these models trained from these different chunks? I would like to use all these trained models for prediction.

I am familiar with DASK and other alternatives but I would like to use Pandas.

```
pipelines = {
    'lasso' : make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), Lasso(random_state=123))
}

for key, value in pipelines.items():
    print( key, type(value) )

# Lasso hyperparameters
lasso_hyperparameters = { 
    'lasso__alpha' : [0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 5, 10] 
}

hyperparameters = {
'lasso' : lasso_hyperparameters
}

# Create empty dictionary called fitted_models
fitted_models = {}

# Create cross-validation object from pipeline and hyperparameters
model = GridSearchCV(pipeline, hyperparameters[name], cv=10, n_jobs=-1)

def train(X_train, y_train):  
    # Fit model on X_train, y_train
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Store model in fitted_models[name] 
    fitted_models[name] = model

    # Print '{name} has been fitted'
    print(name, 'has been fitted.')
    print ("__________________________________")
    print (model.cv_results_)


for df in pd.read_csv('train_V2.csv', chunksize=100000):
    df = df.dropna()
    df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['matchType'])
    df_train = df.drop(['Id', 'groupId', 'matchId'], axis = 1)
    y = df_train.winPlacePerc       
    X = df_train.drop('winPlacePerc', axis=1)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                    test_size=0.2, 
                                                    random_state=1234)
    X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
    X_test = np.asarray(X_test)
    y_train = np.asarray(y_train)
    y_test = np.asarray(y_test)

    train(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: `name` should also be defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "stochastic optimization". You don't need to fit separate models and then combine them.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I am doing this is because I have some 40 million rows and total data size is 650 mb. I started getting memory errors and hence decided to go with chunking

Comment: Same thing - do one update per batch.

Comment: Alright. Any reading material or source to read up? Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent
For lasso you'll need something different, such as stochastic ADMM or friends. You don;t need to know the details, there are many open-source implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor` with L1 penalty, which is equivalent to a Lasso.

This has a `.partial_fit` implementation to incrementally train the model with the chunked datasets, rather than training separate models.

E.g.

```
for epoch in epochs:
    for df in pd.read_csv('train_V2.csv', chunksize=100000):
        model.partial_fit(*args)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can got 2 ways:

- Either you ensemble all your models results with a [Voting
  Regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingRegressor.html).
- You incrementally train your model

Given your use case I would go for the incremental training. Nevertheless, not all scikit-learn models support incremental training. You can check the list of classifiers that support incremental [training here](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html).

As you are using a simple LASSO model, you can with SDGRegressor with L1 regularization.